# Entity Framework 6 and DBContext or DBQuery or DBSet or ObjectQuery with scalar variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to pass a variable to my DBContext extension. It works fine with a fixed string but when I try to use a variable I get the error "Must declare the scalar variable @p_linq_0"

```
        var pn = "6-10064-01";
        // put query results into datatable
        var query = db.SWD_0004.Where(p => p.Part_Number == pn) as DbQuery<SWD_0004>;
        var numResults = query.Count();
        DataTable dt = db.DataTable(query.ToString());

        // gets column names and put into array
        List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        string[] columnList = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                             .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                             .ToArray();
        var rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
        var columnCount = dt.Columns.Count;

        for (var j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
        {

            for (var i = 1; i < columnCount; i++) // skip ID column
            {
                var columnName = columnList[i];
                var data = list[j][i].ToString();
                lstName.Items.Add(columnName);
                lstData.Items.Add(data);
            }
        }

public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static DataTable DataTable(this DbContext context, string query)
    {
        DbProviderFactory dbFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(context.Database.Connection);

        using (var cmd = dbFactory.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = context.Database.Connection;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            using (DbDataAdapter adapter = dbFactory.CreateDataAdapter())
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried a few conversion methods to ObjectQuery, DBQuery, etc with no result. I'm so confused need some direction please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer I was looking for!

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/convert-linq-query-result-to-datatable/

Comment: This solved the variable problem now how do I get the query results to a DataGridView for debugging purposes?

Comment: Getting back to this and I find myself at the same problem. The solution I had earlier is fine if you only have a couple fields but Now I'm working with a database with many fields. I need to get the DataTable so I can get the row and column info to display in a listbox.